# Symfony KnpMenuBundle showing error [MenuBuilder As a Service]

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3, knpmenubundle

I'm using sumfony 3.3.10, I have installed a fresh project of symfony and I added knpMenuBundle using this command,

```
composer require knplabs/knp-menu-bundle "^2.0"
```

Now I followed everything exactly as mentioned here http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/menu_builder_service.html

and added this line `{{ knp_menu_render('main') }}` in default/index.html.twig file.

Now when I execute the project, its showing me this error,

```
[InvalidArgumentException]


Menu builder services must be public but "app.menu_builder" is a private service.
```

**config.yml**

```
knp_menu:
        # use "twig: false" to disable the Twig extension and the TwigRenderer
        twig:
            template: KnpMenuBundle::menu.html.twig
        #  if true, enables the helper   for PHP templates
        templating: false
        # the renderer to use, list is also available by default
        default_renderer: twig
```

**MenuBuilder.php**

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;

    class MenuBuilder
{
    private $factory;

    /**
     * @param FactoryInterface $factory
     *
     * Add any other dependency you need
     */
    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function createMainMenu(array $options)
     {
        $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));
        // ... add more children

        return $menu;
     }
 }
```

**services.yml**

```
app.menu_builder:
            class: AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
            arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]
            tags:
                - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createMainMenu, alias: main } # The alias is what is used to retrieve the menu
```

How can I resolve it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `public: true` to the app.menu_builder service in services.php,

```
app.menu_builder:
        class: AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        public: true
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createMainMenu, alias: main } # The alias is what is used to retrieve the menu
```

And everything is working fine now.

Refer : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html#marking-services-as-public-private